# Execution of a command locally after ssh tunneling

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, script

I have a script file `./run_app.sh` which contains of the following:

```
ssh -L 8888:localhost:8888 ubuntu@address
./run_website.sh   # it should be executed locally
```

but it tries to run the second line on the remote machine. Actually, I want to run it on my pc. Any idea?

Comment: Add the `-N` flag to the `ssh` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Super User.

After `ssh -L 8888:localhost:8888 ubuntu@address`, your script founds itself on the remote server.

You can pass the flags `-fN` to `ssh` (`-f` is for *fork into background* and `-N` is *run no command*).

Then, **after the tunnel is established**, your script resumes execution on the next line *on your machine*.

The downside is that the `ssh` connection *will* remain in the background even after your script is finished.

A workaround is ditching the `-N` flag and execute `sleep 10` on the remote server:

```
ssh -f -L 8888:localhost:8888 ubuntu@address sleep 10
```

This way, if the tunnel is not used, either when `run_website.sh` terminates or after 10 seconds if the script won't use the tunnel (i.e. fails for some reason), it will disconnect automaticaly.

This obviously assumes that `run_website.sh` uses the tunnel.

If you don't care about automatically terminating the tunnel, then go ahead and simply use `-fN`:

```
ssh -fN -L 8888:localhost:8888 ubuntu@address
```

You can kill the `ssh` process later if you need.

Comment: “You can kill the ssh process later if you need” FYI, how to do this is explained in the answer to this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389014/getting-a-pid-for-an-ssh-process-that-backgrounded-itself