# Bash script for SSH and echo

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to have something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
ssh 10.0.0.1
vncviewer
```

However, I want "vncviewer" command to be launched at the same time, and so that it does not interrupt with SSH asking me for password.

Comment: Do you want to run `vncviewer` on the remote server or locally?

Comment: Locally. Should have mentioned - i add -L port:host:port.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to run vncviewer on the local machine, but only after you have entered your password for ssh, you can make a conditional link between the two commands

```
ssh 10.0.0.1 && vncviewer
```

Comment: I want vncviewer to launch on local machine.

Comment: In that case, your script probalby should look like this:

    vncviewer & 
    ssh 10.0.0.1

Comment: I tried that. It messes up with ssh asking me for a password. It somehow inputs a wrong one twice, and I am not able to do anything any more, just ctrl-c.

Comment: What do you mean “it messes up with ssh”...are you saying you can’t see the SSH prompt for passwords?  Vncviewer is not piping input to ssh in any of the command lines you’ve given, so it wouldn’t be sending ipasswords.  SSH on the other hand CAN tell if you don’t have a tty open, nor a public key available.

Comment: Yes, I login without keys, only with a password. And I can't enter them in this case.

Comment: OK, to make sure I understand, you want to start ssh, enter passwords, and then have vncviewer running, so sounds like your best choice would be to setup the execution of vncviewer to occur after a successful authentication to your remote server:

    ssh 10.0.0.1 && vncviewer

Now, ssh will initiate, request your password while it still has control of the tty, and only IF your ssh connection is established, pass the screen on to vncviewer.

Comment: Yes, that would work for me. Thank you, will try tomorrow.

Comment: Using `&&` will not run `vncviewer` until `ssh` has exited, i.e. after the connection has opened *and closed*. See ["Execution of a command locally after ssh tunneling"](https://superuser.com/questions/1364162/execution-of-a-command-locally-after-ssh-tunneling) (thanks @KamilMaciorowski)  for a better answer.